# Working with CSVParser and Formatter to return a List of records

Tags: java

I am using `compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'`

I was expecting that the code below would return 3 items,
but it only returns 1 item.
How might I make it return 3 items?

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
return CSVParser.parse(format.format(new Object[]{"cool", "nice", 5}), format).getRecords()
```

I understand that it returns one item as there is just one record.
So how can I get that record values as a list?

Comment: new Object[][] ?

Comment: @K.Nicholas how do you populate it?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Oh I think that I unerstand what you are saying. Basicaly I only got one record. So how can I get my values back as a list?

Comment: `format.format` accepts a vararg parameter, perhaps you could try `format.format("cool", "nice", 5)`?

Comment: @msrd0 it's just a java formatting, the result will be equivalent to what I have.

Comment: since there's only one record you will have to iterate over the values to prepare your self a list

Comment: ok sorry, unfortunately the javadoc for that method is very short and not too helpful

Comment: @DwB's answer gets you the `List` you're asking for, but if all you really need is a concise way to iterate over the values in a row, you might want to look at `iterator().forEach(value -> /* do something */)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CSVParser.getRecords()` method returns a `List<CSVRecord>`.

If you want the data in a different format,
then you will need to transform the data in your code.

Since `CSVRecord` implements `Iterable<String>`,
you can iterate through the columns of each record and build a structure (`List` in your case) of your choosing.
The code will be similar to this (caveat,
I'm not going to compile my example code):

```
private List<String> convertCSVRecord(
    final CSVRecord record)
{
    final List<String> returnValue = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (final String currentValue : record)
    {
        returnValue.add(currentValue);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

`List.addAll(record)` might work,
give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to prepare your own list from it.

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
CSVRecord record = CSVParser.parse(format.format("cool", "nice", 5), format).getRecords().get(0);
Iterator iterator = record.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    // Add to a list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is messy but it works for the original question for dealing with an Object[][]. However, it assumes the char[] in `CSVParser` is large enough to handle the results.

```
public class CsvPlay
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        new CsvPlay().run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception {
        CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
        Object[][] objectLines = {{"cool"},  {"nice"}, {5}};
        System.out.println( 
            CSVParser.parse(new MyReader(format, objectLines), format).getRecords() 
        );
    }

    class MyReader extends Reader {
        private final CSVFormat format;
        private Object[][] objectLines;
        private int line = 0;
        public MyReader(CSVFormat format, Object[][] objectLines) {
            this.format = format;
            this.objectLines = objectLines;
        }
        @Override
        public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
        {
            if ( line >= objectLines.length) return -1;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(format.format(objectLines[line++])).append('\n');
            sb.getChars(0, sb.length(), cbuf, 0);
            return sb.length();
        }
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {}
    }
}
```